# GCP: Output CSV file using local-exec in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to create an reporting output file where I am listing all the buckets of different GCP projects.
The challenge is neither it prints out the output on the stdout nor it creates the file.
I can confirm that one bucket is there in the project for testing purposes.

Here is the code:

**main.tf**

`data "google_client_config" "default" {}`

```
resource "null_resource" "list_all_buckets" {
  triggers = {
    filename = "${path.module}/storage_output.csv"
  }

provisioner "local-exec" {
 command ="bash list_buckets.sh ${data.google_client_config.default.access_token} '*<gcp project name in single quote>*' >> storage_ouput.csv"
 working_dir = "${path.module}"
  }
}
```

```
data "local_file" "test" {
   filename = "${null_resource.list_all_buckets.triggers.filename}"
}
```

```
output "result" {
  value = "${data.local_file.test.content}"
}
```

**list_buckets.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly TOKEN="$1"
readonly PROJECT="$2"
readonly URL="https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=${2}"

LIST_BUCKETS="$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer "${TOKEN} ${URL})"
```

Please feel free to ask any questions.

I am expecting a storage_ouput.csv file to be created in the existing module directory.

**Output Truncated**

```
You can apply this plan to save these new output values to the Terraform
state, without changing any real infrastructure.
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
Outputs:
result = ""
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

Comment: So your end goal is to create a file with all buckets listed buckets and their files? If it's the case, did you create these buckets with Terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`provisioners`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax) in Terraform only run on creation or deletion time (defaulted to on create), which means that your script will be only called in the first time your run the plan. That run should create a `storage_ouput.csv` file (which has a typo, unlike the path in your triggers `storage_output.csv`).

For testing purposes only I recreated the following:

```
resource "null_resource" "list_all_buckets" {
  triggers = {
    filename = "${path.module}/storage_output.csv"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "date >> ${path.module}/storage_output.csv"
    working_dir = path.module
  }
}

data "local_file" "test" {
  filename = null_resource.list_all_buckets.triggers.filename
}

output "result" {
  value = data.local_file.test.content
}
```

which runs [`date`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command and writes it to `storage_output.csv`. When running this for the first time it creates the CSV file on the current directory, but if I run it again nothing will happen since the `null_resource` was already created.

To force-recreating this I would need to `taint` it, or I run:

```
terraform apply --replace null_resource.list_all_buckets
```

Which force recreating `null_resource`, thus executing the script in your provisioned.

---

As Hashicorp mention in their documentation:

> [Use provisioners as a last resort](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort). There are better alternatives for most situations.

You may want to have a look at Google Storage's data sources like:

- [`google_storage_bucket`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources)

Or, if you created these buckets with Terraform you can list your resources with [`show`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/show) or [`state list`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/list). And if they are created in different workspaces you could pull them using [`terraform_remote_state`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/terraform/latest/docs/data-sources/remote_state)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I try to run your code as is, it gives me below error.

 Error: Read local file data source error
│ 
│   with data.local_file.test,
│   on reporting.tf line 41, in data "local_file" "test":
│   41: data "local_file" "test" {
│ 
│ The file at given path cannot be read.
│ 
│ +Original Error: open ./storage_output.csv: no such file or directory

So I guess, we need to create this file in local directory but it contradicts as we want this file to be created dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my example with `${path.module}/storage_output.csv`

Comment: I am able to force the null_resource:

`always_run = "${timestamp()}"`


The code runs fine after it is updated with ${path.module}, but the date value doesn't go inside the `storage_output.csv` file.



Updated code

resource "null_resource" "list_all_buckets" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
    filename = "${path.module}/storage_output.csv"
  }


  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command     = "date >> ${path.module}/storage_output.csv"
      working_dir = path.module
  }
}

The output of the job:
[output] https://controlc.com/b9606b2a

Comment: You might be looking at the wrong file (see [other paths](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/references#filesystem-and-workspace-info)), or you might be running this from a CI/CD pipeline in which you are not committing your `storage_output` file, so it gets lost after you finish running your job

Comment: Yes, that's what it was as I was running it from CI/CD pipeline. 
Solution: I added below in my script.
`echo $LIST_BUCKETS >> "./storage_output.json`  
`gsutil cp -r ./storage_output.json gs://example-bucket-for-testing-in-lab/`  

Thanks